# Every Order Topology is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

I have the following proof:

> Let $X$ be an ordered set having at least two elements with the order
>   topology, and let $x,y \in X$. Without loss of generality, let $x < y$. If there is a $z \in X$ with
>   $x < z < y$, then take $A = \{t \in X \mid t < z\}$ and $B = \{t \in X \mid t > z\}$. If not,
>   take $A = \{t \in X \mid t < y\}$ and $B = \{t \in X \mid t > x\}$. Either way, note $x \in A$, 
>   $y \in B$, and $A \cap B = \emptyset$, as needed.

Why in the second case is the intersection empty? I don't understand why this is true.

Comment: This site uses MathJax for formulas: see [math notation guide](//math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $z \in A \cap B$. Then $z < y$ (from $z \in A$) and $x < z$ (from $z \in B$). So then $x < z < y$ but no such point existed by assumption, as we are in the second case.  Contradiction, so $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no $z$ satisfying $x < z < y$, it follows that $y$ is the least upper bound for $x$ in this order. They are "next to" each other in the order in the way that $1$ and $2$ are "next to" each other in the usual order on the integers.

The set $A$ consists of all $t$ that are strictly less than $y$. The largest of these is $x$, so I think it would be more clear to write $A = \{t \in X \mid t \leq x\}$.

Similarly, the set $B$ consists of all $t$ that are strictly greater than $x$. The smallest of these is $y$, so I think it would be more clear to write $B = \{t \in X \mid t \geq y\}$.

The sets $A$ and $B$ can have no elements in common. Any element of $A$ is less or equal $x$, and therefore strictly less than $y$.